# How to fix “fastboot FAILED (command write failed (No such file or directory))” error?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, xiaomi

I was trying to flash TWRP recovery image in my MI 8 SE on my windows 10 laptop. I can detect my device in fastboot mode, but when i try to flash the image i get this error

```
target didn't report max-download-size
sending 'recovery' (25668 KB)...
FAILED (command write failed (No such file or directory))
finished. total time: 0.008s
```

My phone then exits from the fastboot mode and i get a black screen with a tiny text at the top left corner of the screen "Press any button to exit" or something like that. When i try to flash the same recovery imaget on my windows 7 pc it flashes without any problem. Not sure what the problem is i've tried installing drivers for the phone and trying different usb ports but nothing help. I can detect the phone when it's turned with no problem.

Comment: fastboot oem device-info

Comment: sorry did not read. this question is not related to android

Comment: maybe you should use fasboot from cmd.exe instead of powershell